# UICollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier causing performance issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, uicollectionview

I am just beginning to use collection view. It's an empty collection view cell haven't added anything yet. I just thought to see how it looks first, later would be adding more UI elements.

But noticing scrolling is not smooth. It takes a moment before starts scrolling. Once started scrolling it runs well till scroll ends. But again it happens when it has to start scrolling.

Running on instruments tells that deque takes time.

```
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

My complete cellForItemAtIndexPath is as given below:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

 static NSString *reuseCellIdentifier = @"Reuse";

UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
//cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
//cell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
//cell.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
return cell;
}
```

Commented lines has no effect when uncommented.

Is there anything i can do to improve the performance? My environment is iOS 7 simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry, iOS7 simulator doesn't perform really well, on a device there shouldn't be any performance issues.

Comment: True. Usually Simulator does well due to more RAM and we check on device to confirm it works well under constrained resources. This is an odd case. Thanks.